# Java 2d map from x and y coordinates?

Tags: java, dictionary, coordinates, slam

I amlooking for a simple way to create a 2d map from x and y coordinates. The program should read a text file with distance measures separated with a comma in (360 measures for every degree), convert these into coordinates, and then create a map, where the dots are connected so it looks more like a map:) Also, a center point would be great, to know from where the measurements were taken.

The calculation is not the problem, however, I don't really know how to convert it into a map...

P.S The output should be something like in the picture
[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnOtJ.png)

Due to lack of knowledge, I was not really able to try many things :/